# How to change default JSDoc Text Color?

Tags: javascript, gulp, jsdoc, jsdoc3, jsdoc2md

I am using `JSDoc` to generate Documentation for my JS library. The default HTML content generated from JSDoc has gray color text and very hard to read. Now, I would like to change text color to black/blue. is there any way to change text color or background color?

Comment: inspect the element and chage the color  code {
  background-color: #00 !important;
}

Comment: Looking for an automated way something like specifying some JSDoc or gulp configurations or some other configs.

Comment: try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ink-docstrap

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to change the default template/styles of JSDoc, and you can achieve that as described [here](http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-default-template.html):

> ### Overriding the default template's layout file
>
> The default template uses a file named `layout.tmpl` to specify the
>   header and footer for each page in the generated documentation. In
>   particular, this file defines which CSS and JavaScript files are
>   loaded for each page. In JSDoc 3.3.0 and later, you can specify your
>   own `layout.tmpl` file to use, which allows you to load your own custom
>   CSS and JavaScript files in addition to, or instead of, the standard
>   files.
>
> To use this feature, set the option `templates.default.layoutFile` to
>   the path to your customized layout file. Relative paths are resolved
>   against the path to the `config.json` file; the current working
>   directory; and the JSDoc directory, in that order.